# For loops with conditional statements to create a new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing a column for site, family and visit number (visit_no). The sites have differing visit numbers (2 or 3) and different families recorded per visit and per site:

```
   site        family visit_no
1    A1  Scarabaeidae        1
2    A1     Clambidae        1
3    A1     Carabidae        1
4    A1     Carabidae        2
5    A1     Clambidae        2
6    A1  Scarabaeidae        2
7    A1     Leiodidae        3
8    A1     Clambidae        3
9    A1     Carabidae        3
10   A2  Scarabaeidae        1
11   A2     Carabidae        1
12   A2 Staphylinidae        1
13   A2 Curculionidae        2
14   A2  Scarabaeidae        2
15   A2 Staphylinidae        2
16   A3 Staphylinidae        1
17   A3     Carabidae        1
18   A3 Curculionidae        1
19   A3     Leiodidae        2
20   A3     Clambidae        2
21   A3      Carbidae        2
22   A3   Phalacridae        3
23   A3     Carabidae        3
24   A3 Curculionidae        3
```

I want to fill a dataframe that records for each visit at each site whether the family Scarabaeidae was present (1) or absent (0). Where a site has a lower visit number than other sites, I want the visit number column to record NA. This would look like so:

```
  site    1    2    3
1   A1    1    1    0
2   A2    1    1    NA
3   A3    0    0    0
```

Is there a way to do this using conditional for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, there's no need to use loops for this kind of thing. Pivot the data into long form, do the calculation and then pivot it to wide form again:

```
library(magrittr)
dat %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(site, visit_no) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(a = dplyr::if_else("Scarabaeidae" %in% family, 1, 0)) %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from="visit_no", values_from="a")
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   site [3]
  site    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1        1     1     0
2 A2        1     1    NA
3 A3        0     0     0
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: `'ifelse' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'`? Could there be a clash between functions within the packages I have loaded?

Comment: Sorry, see edit. I had named the function wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use only `pivot_wider` -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = visit_no, values_from = family, 
                  values_fn = function(x) as.integer("Scarabaeidae" %in% x))
  

#   site    `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A1        1     1     0
#2 A2        1     1    NA
#3 A3        0     0     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(site = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
"A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), family = c("Scarabaeidae", 
"Clambidae", "Carabidae", "Carabidae", "Clambidae", "Scarabaeidae", 
"Leiodidae", "Clambidae", "Carabidae", "Scarabaeidae", "Carabidae", 
"Staphylinidae", "Curculionidae", "Scarabaeidae", "Staphylinidae", 
"Staphylinidae", "Carabidae", "Curculionidae", "Leiodidae", "Clambidae", 
"Carbidae", "Phalacridae", "Carabidae", "Curculionidae"), visit_no = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in one line using `tapply()`.

```
with(dat, tapply(I(family == 'Scarabaeidae'), list(site, visit_no), sum))
#    1 2  3
# A1 1 1  0
# A2 1 1 NA
# A3 0 0  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text='   site        family visit_no
1    A1  Scarabaeidae        1
2    A1     Clambidae        1
3    A1     Carabidae        1
4    A1     Carabidae        2
5    A1     Clambidae        2
6    A1  Scarabaeidae        2
7    A1     Leiodidae        3
8    A1     Clambidae        3
9    A1     Carabidae        3
10   A2  Scarabaeidae        1
11   A2     Carabidae        1
12   A2 Staphylinidae        1
13   A2 Curculionidae        2
14   A2  Scarabaeidae        2
15   A2 Staphylinidae        2
16   A3 Staphylinidae        1
17   A3     Carabidae        1
18   A3 Curculionidae        1
19   A3     Leiodidae        2
20   A3     Clambidae        2
21   A3      Carbidae        2
22   A3   Phalacridae        3
23   A3     Carabidae        3
24   A3 Curculionidae        3')
```